mat-menu with heading accessibility issue
I'm looking to include a heading within a mat-menu using ul and li tags. However, the screen reader fails to announce the heading. Is there an option to add a header or category within a mat-menu while ensuring screen reader accessibility? It seems that because the focus initially goes to the first mat-menu-item, the screen reader might not announce the header associated with the ul and li tags. Does anyone have any insights on how to address this issue, particularly with JAWS/NVDA screen reader?
Here is my HTML
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="A">Link list</button>
<mat-menu #A="matMenu">
  <h2 role="heading">Heading</h2>
  <ul role="menu">
    <li mat-menu-item><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li mat-menu-item><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li mat-menu-item><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</mat-menu>

I'm seeking to ensure that screen readers can properly announce a list with its heading. However, when using mat-menu, the screen reader only reads the mat-menu-list and not the associated heading. How can I ensure that both the list and its heading are read by the screen reader as expected?

Could you try and make this code sample interactive? An element wtih role menu cannot have heading as its child. You can provide a name for the menu with the aria-label attribute. It’s more complicated if you want to provide a visible title. You’d need to change the role of the heading to none and reference it with aria-labelledby to get announced.

Then again, having a title inside the menu is weird and seems like an anti-pattern. Shouldn’t the menu trigger provide the title?
